# React Navigation V5 InitalRouteName not working with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'd like to take the user to the profile page if their information doesn't exist yet. But the initialRouteName isn't working when using conditional rendering with the jwt. Maybe i'm missing a better approach. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function ExploreNavigator() {
  const jwt = useSelector(state => state.session.jwt);
  const { firstName } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      headerMode="screen"
      initialRouteName={firstName ? "Listings" : "Profile"}
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        },
      }}>
      {jwt ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Listings"
            component={ListingsScreen}
            options={{ title: 'My Studios' }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="Onboarding"
            component={OnboardingScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={ProfileScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Sign Up"
            component={SignUpScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code

initialRouteName={firstName? "Listings": "Profile"}
if you look closely, there's no space between firstName and the question mark operator. The code should look like this

initialRouteName={firstName ? "Listings" : "Profile"}

Comment: I just typed that as an example. If set initalRouteName={"Profile"} it still defaults to "Listings".

Comment: Usually, what I do is, instead of having ternary on the jwt token inside the stack navigator I separate the Authentication and the Main stack into their own files and then in a main-navigator file I do ternary which looks like this 
    <NavigationContainer>
      {jwt ? <MainStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I hadn't made a hard refresh on my project. smh. It works fine. Thanks for the help.